# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, google-maps, nullpointerexception

Ive only been programming a few days, so I am struggling to grasp what I am doing wrong here, hoping the community can point me in the right direction..
Here my MainActivity:

```
package com.whatsonwhere.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private LocationClient mLocationClient;
    /*
     * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
     * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
     */
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    // Define a DialogFragment that displays the error dialog
    public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

        // Global field to contain the error dialog
        private Dialog mDialog;

        // Default constructor. Sets the dialog field to null
        public ErrorDialogFragment() {
            super();
            mDialog = null;
        }

        // Set the dialog to display
        public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) {
            mDialog = dialog;
        }

        // Return a Dialog to the DialogFragment.
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return mDialog;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

        mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView));
        map = mapFragment.getMap();

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }

    /*
     * Called when the Activity becomes visible.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Connect the client.
        if(isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()){
            mLocationClient.connect();
        }

    }

    /*
     * Called when the Activity is no longer visible.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    /*
     * Handle results returned to the FragmentActivity
     * by Google Play services
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(
            int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Decide what to do based on the original request code
        switch (requestCode) {

            case CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST:
            /*
             * If the result code is Activity.RESULT_OK, try
             * to connect again
             */
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        mLocationClient.connect();
                        break;
                }

        }
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        // Check that Google Play services is available
        int resultCode =  GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        // If Google Play services is available
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
            // In debug mode, log the status
            Log.d("Location Updates", "Google Play services is available.");
            return true;
        } else {
            // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
            Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog( resultCode,
                    this,
                    CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

            // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
            if (errorDialog != null) {
                // Create a new DialogFragment for the error dialog
                ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
                errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);
                errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Location Updates");
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
     * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
     * request the current location or start periodic updates
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Location location = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17);
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the connection to the
     * location client drops because of an error.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the attempt to
     * Location Services fails.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    /*
     * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
     * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
     * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
     * error.
     */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                        this,
                        CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            /*
            * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
            * PendingIntent
            */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry. Location services not available to you", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

and my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.whatsonwhere.app" >
    <permission
        android:name="com.whatsonwhere.app.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.whatsonwhere.app.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.whatsonwhere.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="mykey_here(removed)" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Activity_main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.whatsonwhere.app.MainActivity">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/TopText"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nearme"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/search"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/loc"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally the logcat:

```
03-25 11:28:19.417    6650-6650/com.whatsonwhere.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-25 11:28:19.417    6650-6650/com.whatsonwhere.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415e88b0)
03-25 11:28:19.417    6650-6650/com.whatsonwhere.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.whatsonwhere.app/com.whatsonwhere.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.whatsonwhere.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 11:28:19.537    6650-6682/com.whatsonwhere.app W/ActivityThread﹕ ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
03-25 11:28:21.477    6650-6650/com.whatsonwhere.app I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 6650 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What is line 71 MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

And

```
mapFragment =((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView));   
map = mapFragment.getMap();
```

The compiler looks for `R.id.mapView` in `R.layout.activity_main` .The names are case sensitive.
The line:

```
map=mapFragment.getMap():
```

throws a NPE as the `mapView` isn't found in its respective layout. Check the names if `id`(s) and whether it is declared in the mentioned `layout`.

Also, alternatively..you can use:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.mapView)).getMap();
```

saves a variable declaration and l-o-c, if not necessary otherwise.

Add fragment like this:

```
 <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: Not sure Im understing here - Ill add my activity main into the top post

Comment: @Jimmyeao you have `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` but when you initialize you have  `mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView));`. Its should be  `SupportMapFragment`. The map object can be null

Comment: @Jimmyeao what's your min sdk ? coz if you want to support below 11 then you need to use `SupportMapFragment`

Answer (score 0):

`mapFragment` is `null` after the `findFragmentById()` call. Please make sure you have id = `mapView` (case-sensitive) inside `activity_main.xml`. If you have it there, you can also try to move the work with `MapFragment` from `onCreate` to `onStart` or `onResume`

Comment: Commenting out this line has no effect - the app still crashes with the same error

Comment: @Jimmyeao but you shouldn't comment this line. If you comment it, mapFragment will be definitely `null`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when the activity is created, the map is not initialised. This leads to **NullPointerException**.

You must move the code mapFragment etc from `onCreate` to `onResume`.

This will ensure that the activity is created and in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Change here from

```
mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView));
```

to

```
mapFragment = ((MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView));
```

Because in your xml file you are using

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

Comment: But make one correction which he made a mistake.And this is not wrong.